# Only the first update-database is working (creates the DB) then update-database does nothing

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

This is an EF Core, ASP.NET Core 3 Preview 5 project in VS 2019. All is working for

```
PM>Add-Migration Initial
PM>Update-Database
```

The SQL Server db created correctly based on MyDbContext and Startup.cs and appsettings.json connection string. (so everything is in place)

However if I change MyDbContext either adding a new DbSet or adding a property to an existing entity and run `Update-Database` nothing happens. No error message.

What I've tried so far:

- Completely clean the project either in VS 2019 either by manually in file system
- Exit VS, start VS
- Deleting the migration folder in the project and `DROP` the database in SQL Server and starting from ground zero

Comment: Did you do `Add-Migration whatever` after the changes you've done? (before doing `Update-Database`).

Comment: When no database and migration were exits I did `Add-Migration`, then `Update-Database`. The database in SQL Server correctly created. The migration folder also creating in my project. Then I modified my model class, and again did `Update-Database` but nver happened, no error message, and no changes in the SQL Server database

Comment: Any changes to the Models/Entities or adding new DbSet require adding new migration again before doing `Update-Database` so that the database schema be in sync with the application's data models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind `Migrations` is to update the database schema and keep it in sync with your application data models (entities), so that you do not need to drop the database and re-create it again (which would cause data loss).

So whenever you do any changes to the Models/DbContext you need to `Add-Migration`, then do `Update-Database`.

---

For more information about migrations [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#create-a-migration).